# How often does a character occur in the first position vs the second position of a string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to answer the question:

> How often does a character occur in the first position versus the
>   second position of a string?

using a SQL query on Mysql.

However I get a syntax error.

The code:

```
SELECT 
    onechar, 
    ASCII(onechar) as asciival, 
    COUNT(*) as cnt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pos = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pos_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pos = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pos_2
FROM (
    (SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(`city`, 1, 1) as onechar, 
        1 as pos
    FROM `orders`  
    WHERE LEN(`city` >= 1 )

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(`city`, 2, 1) as onechar, 
        2 as pos
    FROM `orders`  
    WHERE LEN(`city` >= 2)
    ) 
GROUP BY onechar
ORDER BY onechar
```

The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'GROUP BY onechar  ORDER BY onechar  LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Tried several ways without success.

Anyone could give me a light on this problem?

Comment: You have unmatched parentheses in your query.

Comment: Hi Felix, can you guide me where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parenthesis look incorrect and the query is missing an alias for the derived table. Also, because mysql evaluates booleans to 1 or 0 you can simplify your `sum` statements. Try this:

```
SELECT onechar, ASCII(onechar) as asciival, COUNT(*) as cnt,
SUM(pos = 1) as pos_1,
SUM(pos = 2) as pos_2
FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(`city`, 1, 1) as onechar, 1 as pos
    FROM `orders` WHERE LENGTH(`city`) >= 1 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(`city`, 2, 1) as onechar, 2 as pos
    FROM `orders` WHERE LENGTH(`city`) >= 2
) t
GROUP BY onechar
ORDER BY onechar
```

Comment: It gives me an error #1305 - FUNCTION sql_test.LEN does not exist

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull the correct name is `length` not `len` see update. also, the condition should be outside the function

Comment: even changing the LEN for LENGHT I still get "Every derived table must have its own alias". Not sure what it meas. Is there a way around this to answer the question ?

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull did you include the alias `t` (i.e. before `group by`)?

Comment: SELECT onechar, ASCII(onechar) as asciival, COUNT(*) as cnt,
SUM(CASE WHEN pos = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pos_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN pos = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as pos_2

FROM ((SELECT SUBSTRING(`city`, 1, 1) as onechar, 1 as pos
FROM `orders`  WHERE LENGHT(`city` >= 1 ))
UNION ALL
(SELECT SUBSTRING(`city`, 2, 1) as onechar, 2 as pos
FROM `orders`  WHERE LENGHT(`city` >= 2)
) ) t
GROUP BY onechar

Comment: Now I get a strange error: #1305 - FUNCTION sql_test.LENGHT does not exist

Comment: Sure , how silly I am ;( . Thanks a lot , it worked !

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a number of closing bracket.

```
FROM (
    (SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(`city`, 1, 1) as onechar, 
        1 as pos
    FROM `orders`  
    WHERE LEN(`city` >= 1 )
     )
    UNION ALL

    (SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(`city`, 2, 1) as onechar, 
        2 as pos
    FROM `orders`  
    WHERE LEN(`city` >= 2)
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working I get the error : Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Every derived table must indeed have an alias. ( Note the as custom alias). Forgot to mention, replace LEN to LENGTH